# Extracting lines between files using grep

Tags: database, linux, command-line, grep

I have two files, file1.txt and file2. txt

file1.txt contains multiple strings such as:

```
Little.1
Little.2
Little.3
```

and the file2.txt contains strings such as:

```
XYQ Little.1 AGTAGT
ABC Little.12 ATCGCT
GDT Little.3 CGTAGT
```

How do I use grep so that when I use file1 to grep file2 I only return:

```
XYG Little.1 AGTAGT
GDT Little.3 CGTAGT
```

Because they match exactly?

Answer (score 1):

`grep -w` and `-f` are done for this:

```
$ grep -wf file1 file2
XYQ Little.1 AGTAGT
GDT Little.3 CGTAGT
```

From `man grep`:

> **-f FILE, --file=FILE**
>
> Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  The empty file contains zero
>   patterns, and therefore matches nothing.  (-f is specified by POSIX.)
>
> **-w, --word-regexp**
>
> Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches that form whole words.
>   The test is that the matching substring must either be at the
>   beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent
>   character. Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or
>   followed by a non-word constituent character.  Word-constituent
>   characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.

---

Note that without `-w` it will match other cases:

```
$ grep -f file1 file2
XYQ Little.1 AGTAGT
ABC Little.12 ATCGCT
GDT Little.3 CGTAGT
```